# sparse matrix constraints constrOptim

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, sparse-matrix

I everybody,

I have a function to optimize, subject to linear constraints. 
I am actually using `maxLik` R-package, but this is a wrapper for various method, thus what I am actually running in `constrOptim`.

The problem is the following: I have a matrix of constraints which is n^2 x n, but n is ~ 10^3, so the matrix is huge and the routine stops for memory problems.

`Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105`

It seemed quite natural to me to shift to sparse matrices (indeed my matrix is very sparse) with the `Matrix` package, but I always get the following error

`Error: Matrices must have same dimensions in ineqA * gi.old`

even for small n.
Does it mean that sparseMatrix is not supported in `constrOptim`?
Do you know any way out?

## reproducible example

you can find the dataset I am using to optimize here:
http://konect.uni-koblenz.de/downloads/extraction/opsahl.tar.bz2

and here you have the code

```
#read edgelist
edgelist <- read.table('out.opsahl-usairport',skip=2)
colnames(edgelist) = c('V1','V2','weight')
require(igraph)
g = graph_from_data_frame(edgelist)
s_in = strength(g,v=V(g), mode= 'in')
s_out = strength(g,v=V(g),mode='out')
n = length(s_in)


# optimization function

objective_fun = function(x){
    theta_out = x[1:(length(x)/2)]; theta_in = x[(length(x)/2+1):length(x)];

    llikelihood(s_out,s_in,theta_out,theta_in)
  }

llikelihood = function(s_out,s_in,theta_out, theta_in){
  theta_sum_mat = outer(theta_out,rep(1,length(theta_out))) + outer(rep(1,length(theta_in)),theta_in)
  theta_sum_mat = log(1-exp(-theta_sum_mat))
  diag(theta_sum_mat) = 0 # avoid self loops
  f = -sum(s_out*theta_out+s_in*theta_in) + sum(theta_sum_mat)
  f
}    

#choose appropriate starting point
starting_point = function(s_out,s_in){
  s_tot = sum(s_in) # =sum(s_out)
  s_mean = mean(mean(s_in),mean(s_out))
  z = log((s_tot + s_mean^2)/(s_mean^2))
  list(theta_out = rep(1,length(s_out)), theta_in=rep(z-1,length(s_in))) # starting parameters
}

#gradient

grad = function(x){
  theta_out = x[1:(length(x)/2)]; theta_in = x[(length(x)/2+1):length(x)];
  ret = grad_fun(s_out,s_in,theta_out,theta_in)
  ret
}

grad_fun = function(s_out,s_in, theta_out, theta_in){
  theta_sum_mat = outer(theta_out,rep(1,length(theta_out))) + outer(rep(1,length(theta_in)),theta_in)
  theta_sum_mat = exp(-theta_sum_mat)/(1-exp(-theta_sum_mat))
  diag(theta_sum_mat) = 0 # avoid self loops
  c(-s_out + rowSums(theta_sum_mat), -s_in + colSums(theta_sum_mat))
}


#constraints
  constraints = function(n){
    a1 = Diagonal(n); a2 = sparseMatrix(c(1:n),rep(1,n), x=1, dims=c(n,n)) # Diagonal is a sparse diagonal matrix
    a12 = cBind(a1,a2)
    a12[1,] = 0 # avoid self loops
    dd = function(j){
      sparseMatrix(c(1:n),rep(j,n), x=rep(1,n), dims=c(n,n))
    }
    b1 = sparseMatrix(i=1, j=1, x=1, dims=c(n^2,1)) # 1,0,0,...  n^2 vector
    for(j in c(2:n)) {
      a = cBind(Diagonal(n),dd(j))
      a[j,]=0 # avoid self loops
      a12 = rBind(a12, a)
      b1[(j-1)*n+j] = 1 # add 1 to ''self loops'' rows, in order to have the inequality satisfied
    }
    return(list(A=a12, B=b1))
  }

  # starting point
  theta_0 = starting_point(s_out,s_in)
  x_0 =  c(theta_0$theta_out, theta_0$theta_in)

  #constraints
  constr = list(ineqA=constraints(n)$A, ineqB=constraints(n)$B)

  # optimization 
  co = maxControl(printLevel = 1, iterlim=500, tol=1e-4)  #tol=1e-8 (def)  iterlim=150 (def)  
  res = maxLik(objective_fun, grad=grad, start=x_0, constraints=constr, control=co)
```

Comment: Is your objective function linear, too? Then you might switch to a linear solver.

Comment: no, unfortunately it is not

Comment: Its easier to help you if you provide [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data.

Comment: right, now you can see the code

Comment: Unfortunately it seems too difficult. `constrOptim()` and `maxLik()` can take sparse matrix (class `dgCMatrix`) as an arguments, but if it is large they can't. I didn't peruse their codes, but I guess `ineqA %*% param + ineqB`'s return matrix causes error, maybe its length is too long (note: it isn't `dgCmatrix` because `dgCmatrix %*% not dgCmatrix = dgeMatrix`). I try functional constraints with `alabama::auglag` and `Rsolnp::solnp`, but they can't treat class `dgCmatrix` that constraints `function()` returns, and they complain too long when use `as.matrix(dgCmatrix)` as return matrix....

Comment: @cuttlefish44 you say ``maxLik`` can take sparseMatrix as input, but I get the same error even for very small networks (=small n). You can try for instance with this http://konect.uni-koblenz.de/downloads/tsv/moreno_cattle.tar.bz2

Comment: You are right, the example I did is too simple to judge it. In some situation, such as `method = "BFGS"`, `maxLik` and `constrOptim` seem not to treat sparse matrix. When I don't give grad (it means using "Nelder-Mead" method), `res = maxLik(objective_fun, start=x_0, constraints=constr, control=co)` run with moreno data. Thank you for pointing out my mistakes.